# winsock unable to ping URL but able to ping ip

Tags: windows-server-2003, ping

i have a web app on the server that sends emails with aspemail from persists

today it stopped and i get error **Winsock error 11004 (0x2AFC) occurred.**

if i try to ping the host server smtp.gmail.com it won't work, if i try to ping it's ip it works so if i change the host server for the mail send to gmail's ip - it works...

i have tried the reset of the winsock, didn't work

what can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to redirect the DNS request via WinSock proxy. See also: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dns_resolver.aspx

Comment: but it worked until 2 days ago

Comment: Try to find out why DNS resolving is not working trough WinSock.

Comment: Do you use a WinSock proxy? if not, then try to see if you DNS server is reachable from your server. Use: `nslookup smtp.gmail.com`, then try `nslookup smtp.google.com 8.8.8.8`. If the second one is returning the IP of the SMTP server from Google, then you need to update the DNS server configuration for your windows server

Comment: never mind... my stupid friend add a local security policy. add assign to block ip and it blocked all ips